# What is a clean interface to set class variables in a mixin module?

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection, mixins, class-variables

In a Ruby project I'm working on, I add ActiveRecord-style, MVC functionality to model classes with a mixin architecture similar to the following:

```
module Model

  # Classes that mixin this module gain ActiveRecord-style class methods
  # like Model.all, Model.first, Model.last et al.
  #
  # Throughout this module, @@database_bridge will contain a reference to a
  # database ORM bridge, that does the dirty implementation of these methods.

  def all
    # Implementation stuff here, using @@database_bridge as appropriate
  end

  def first
    ...
  end

  # et al

end


class ExampleModel

  extend Model

  # Model-specific implementation goes here...

end
```

Calling `e = ExampleModel.first` would assign the first `ExampleModel` in the database to `e`.

I want to use dependency injection to set `@@database_bridge` at runtime, such that every class containing `extend Model` uses the same, specified ORM object.

How can I do this?

If I could write some kind of helper method to set up that class variable on demand, that would be great.

Comment: If anyone is thinking I'd be better inheriting stuff from a base 'Model' class, that really doesn't fit with my class hierarchy.

The framework isn't MVC at its _core_, it simply uses MVC-style class methods as an elegant way to pull stuff from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better solution than the previous, and it's much simpler than I thought (*d'oh!*): **by prefixing a method with `self.` in a mixin module, a public interface to that method via `Module.method` becomes available.**

Thus, we simply **add a setter** to our module, using a `self.attribute_set` statement.

In the above example, the above approach would yield the following code:

```
module Model

  # Classes that mixin this module gain ActiveRecord-style class methods
  # like Model.all, Model.first, Model.last et al.
  #
  # Throughout this module, @@database_bridge will contain a reference to a
  # database ORM bridge, that does the dirty implementation of these methods.

  def all
    # Implementation stuff here, using @@database_bridge as appropriate
  end

  def first
    ...
  end

  def self.set_database_bridge(ref_to_new_bridge)
    @@database_bridge = ref_to_new_bridge
    ## any additional intialisation/sanitisation logic goes here
  end

  # et al

end


class ExampleModel

  extend Model

  # Model-specific implementation goes here...

end
```

Calling `Model.set_database_bridge` would allow us to **pass in a new database bridge**.

If we don't actually need any initialisation or sanitisation logic in our helper function, **there is another, more elegant approach - add an `attr_accessor` within a `class << self` block**, thus:

```
module Model

  # ...

  class << self
    attr_accessor :database_bridge
  end

end
```

This way, **we can call Ruby's standard *setter method***: `Model.database_bridge = the_new_bridge`.

**Sweet.**

Comment: This is really the answer I was looking for, and will tick it tomorrow, if no one has any specific 'gotchas' for this approach.

Comments and suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer, but is *a potential solution*: **you can call `class_variable_set` on a *module*, by calling `Module.class_variable_set`.**

Thus, you could create a helper method, in an appropriate namespace somewhere, that calls `Module.class_variable_set :@@class_var, "new value"`.

For the example above, my helper function would like this:

```
def set_database_bridge(new_bridge)
  Model.class_variable_set :@@database_bridge, new_bridge
end
```

**This solution creates a degree of coupling between the helper function and the implementation of the `Model` mixin, as if the name of @@database_bridge were to change, the helper function would break.**

If anyone has an idea for a more loosely coupled/more encapsulated solution (where we perhaps encapsulate the helper function within `Model` somewhere), that would be awesome!